# Creating an instance of a COM interop class

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-assembly, com-interop, coreldraw

I am trying to open CorelDRAW from within my program using C#. So far I have been able to do so by referencing the appropriate com library and calling

```
CorelDRAW.Application draw = new CorelDRAW.Application();
draw.Visible = true;
```

However, I would like my program to work with any version of CorelDRAW that supports interop. I am attempting to use reflection to load the interop library at runtime, where the specific dll can be chosen for the correct version. From looking around I have tried the following.

```
string path = "Interop.CorelDRAW.dll";
Assembly u = Assembly.LoadFile(path);
Type testType = u.GetType("CorelDRAW.Application");

if (testType != null)
{
    object draw = u.CreateInstance("CorelDRAW.Application");

    FieldInfo fi = testType.GetField("Visible");
    fi.SetValue(draw, true);
}
```

The program fails at `u.CreateInstance...` fails because `CorelDRAW.Application` is an interface, not a class. I have also tried replacing `CorelDRAW.Application` with `CorelDRAW.ApplicationClass` as that is available when I browse through Interop.CorelDRAW as a resource, but then `u.getType...` fails.

How can I get this to work? Thank you!

Comment: I've gotten this working to some extent. I've created 5 additional projects in my C# solution, each one containing a reference to a specific version of Corel. Then that project has a function which returns my CorelDRAW.Application object. Then I can use reflection on that object back in the main program. Not the cleanest, but so far it is sufficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create instances of registered ActiveX objects using following construct:

```
Type type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("CorelDRAW.Application", true);
object vc = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

Then you have 3 options, on how to work with returned object.

1. Casting returned object to real CorelDRAW.Application interface, but for this you need to reference some CorelDraw library which contains it, and probably this will produce versioning problems.
2. Reflection, which you mention in your question.
3. Use dynamic keyword, so you can call existing methods and properties just like it was a real CorelDraw class/interface.

   ```
   Type type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("CorelDRAW.Application", true);
   dynamic vc = (dynamic)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
   vc.Visible = true;
   ```

Comment: I was literally for 6 hours searching for this answer, my code was working but no window appearing o screen, the secret was just set the Visible property to true, thanks man

Answer (score 1):

```
  System.Reflection.Assembly assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(fullPath);
  dynamic app = assembly.CreateInstance("CorelDRAW.ApplicationClass", true);
```

this is gonna work

Answer (score 0):

I know that's a very (extremely) old question, but I think that could be helpful to post some updated code to future programmers that was in trouble like me for many hours.

CorelDraw 2021

```
Type corelType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("CorelDRAW.Application.23");

Application app = (Application)Activator.CreateInstance(desktopType);

app.Visible = true;

Console.ReadLine(); // Needed in console project to keep CorelDraw opened
```