# How to Get running CorelDraw Application object for automation under C#

Tags: c#, coreldraw

I can get a reference to a running CorelDRAW X6 application using VBA (in Excel), but *only* if I explicitly provide an empty string for the Pathname argument...

```
  'This fails
  Set appCD = GetObject(, "CorelDraw.Application")
  'This works
  Set appCD = GetObject("", "CorelDraw.Application")
```

Under C#, I'm trying to get CorelDraw using GetActiveObject, but this line appears to fail:

```
Application = (TApplication)Marshal.GetActiveObject("CorelDraw.Application");
```

Any ideas on how to get the object?

EDIT: Looks like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/770173/how-to-get-excel-instance-or-excel-instance-clsid-using-the-process-id) question might be the way to go.

Comment: This question doesn't seem to involve vb.net. Perhaps you meant to use the vba tag rather than the vb.net tag (vba and vb.net are not the same).

Comment: Indeed, I was going to speculate about using VB.Net's GetObject method to get the object, just like VBA's approach, but I decided I didn't really want to go down that road.

Comment: Then I suggest you remove the vb.net tag.

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12926102/creating-an-instance-of-a-com-interop-class